# JDeveloper ADF: CreateInsert auto committing?

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, jspx

I'm currently starting with ADF Faces technology as well as with JDeveloper. I have a .jspx page where I open a popup in which exists an ADF Form binded with a View Object. Whenever the popup opens it calls a createInsert action, but then some error messages popup as if somewhere a validation is being executed.

**Things I've considered or tried so far:**

1. The "SKIP VALIDATION" property of the page is set to TRUE. I don't
   know what else to try.
2. Auto Submit property of each input are set to FALSE.

**Consideration**

I think the createInsert action is auto submitting but like I said I just started using these technologies a few days ago. So perhaps this "weird behaviour" is being caused by other settings I haven't considered yet.

[image: Popup message errors]

Here's the code I use when the popup opens (PopUpFecthListener)

```
public void createInsert(PopupFetchEvent popupFetchEvent) {
    try {

        System.out.println("Inside function");

        ADFUtil.invokeEL("#{bindings.CreateInsertVariable.execute}");
        Util.getAppModuleImpl().getFurVariableView1().getCurrentRow().setAttribute("Estado", "I");


        System.out.println("Function has been executed");
    } catch (Exception e) {

        Util.logErrorJava("Error", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Here's the method in which I get the AppModuleImpl

```
    public static AppModuleImpl getAppModuleImpl() {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ValueBinding vb = context.getApplication().createValueBinding("#{data}");
        BindingContext bc = (BindingContext)vb.getValue(context);
        DCDataControl dc = bc.findDataControl("AppModuleDataControl");
        AppModuleImpl module = (AppModuleImpl)dc.getDataProvider();
        return module;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to use immediate attribute for you input controls.
For best understanding of immediate and validation mechanism [read this article](http://adfpractice-fedor.blogspot.com.by/2012/02/understanding-immediate-attribute.html)